# Javascript get callback not working in loop

Tags: javascript, loops, get, each

Below is my script for getting optimized image through javascript.

```
<img data-src='a.jpg'>
<img data-src='b.jpg'>
<img data-src='n.jpg'>


<script>
    $('img').each(function(){
        var datasrc = $(this).data('src');
        $.get('api.php',{"dataa":datasrc},function(result){
            $(this).attr('src',result));
        })
    });
</script>
```

Anyway, `'result'` returns optimized images, but the `$(this) src` not updating. The `src` shows `unknown`

What is wrong here? May be `$(this)` does not work inside `$.get callback` function ?

Please help me

Comment: simplest fix ...change  `function(result){` . to ... `(result) => {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think indeed the second $(this) refers to the this of the call, not the image.
You can try:

```js
$('img').each(function(){
    const image   = $(this),
          datasrc = image.data('src');

    $.get('api.php',{"data":datasrc}, function(result) {
        image.attr('src',result));
    });
});
```